# Firechat/Firebase user moderators

Tags: javascript, wordpress, firebase

I have Firechat powered by Firebase running and integrated with my Wordpress database. It works great, but one thing I'm missing are chat moderators / admins.

From what I can tell from looking at the [rules.json](https://github.com/firebase/firechat/blob/master/rules.json) :

```
"moderators": {
      ".read": "(auth != null)"
    },
    "suspensions": {
      ".write": "(auth != null) && (root.child('moderators').hasChild(auth.uid))",
      ".read": "(auth != null) && (root.child('moderators').hasChild(auth.uid))"
    }
```

...and by a [repository search](https://github.com/firebase/firechat/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=moderator), there seems to be some kind of moderator function. However, I can't find a reference to using it anywhere.

Can you help me understand how the moderator system works? Are they able to control all chat rooms or just one? Are they capable of kick, mute, or ban? How can you set a user as "moderator"?

Answer (score 2):

Firechat, in its current version, gives 'moderators' a special, right-click context menu on chat messages that includes some kick and ban behaviors. Moderators are defined as any record stored in `<root>/moderators/<moderator-user-id>`. In other words, add a record with `<user-id>:true` under `/moderators` in your Firebase to enable that context menu.